# How to access perl hash value (which is an array) from Template Toolkit?

Tags: perl, templates, hash, toolkit

I have assigned a hash in perl as follows:

```
my %myvers;
my @patches = ();
my @mypatches = ();

foreach my $myv ( @{$product->versions} ){

@patches = set_patches($myv->id);   #get the array of patches for the version
foreach(@patches) {
    push @mypatches,@{$_};
    }
$myvers{$myv->name} = @mypatches;
}

$vars->{'myvers'} = \%myvers;
```

When I access the hash in html template with the code below:

```
[% FOREACH key IN myvers.keys %]
alert('[% key %] is [% myvers.$key %]; ');
[% END %]
```

**key** contains the keys and **$key** contains the number of elements in the array for each key assigned above.

I cannot access the values of elements of the array. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is you don't store the elements, you only store the size.

```
$myvers{ $myv->name } = @mypatches;
```

Assigning to a hash value forces a scalar context, so `@mypatches` returns the size of the array. You need to store a reference to the array instead:

```
$myvers{ $myv->name } = [ @mypatches ];
```

It's probably more common to declare the array inside the outer loop and use a reference. In fact, you can skip pushing the elements one by one, as you can push the whole array: `push @mypatches, @patches`, but then, you don't need two arrays at all:

```
my %myvers;

for my $myv (@{ $product->versions }) {
    my @patches = set_patches($myv->id);
    $myvers{ $myv->name } = \@patches;
}

$vars->{myvers} = \%myvers;
```

or, if you really want to be laconic:

```
$myvers{ $_->name } = [ set_patches($_->id) ] for @{ $product->versions };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It worked as I followed your instructions. Thanks also for your prompt response. It made my life easy.

Comment: Being able to expose the hash array elements was enough for me.

Comment: But it did not work if I do not push the elements one by one. It shows **Array(0x...)**, instead of the elements. Is this due to any problem with the reference ? I have the same problem when I push the whole array.

Thanks again for sparing your time and sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @ DipankarGhosh: You have to iterate over the inner array.